# hbase cluster need multiple data node

Tags: hadoop, hbase

According to hbase official tutorial, when configure the hbase distributed cluster, in hbase-sit.xml file , need configure the property hbase.rootdir point to hdfs cluster address.  and, all the hbase data will save on the hdfs.  In this case , will the hbase cluster need multiple    data node ?

Comment: what do you mean need multiple data nodes? Hbase needs to know about the namenode which has information on the datanodes, and hdfs cant function without a datanode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase has nothing to do with the number of DNs you have. But, greater the number of DNs better  performance and availability you get, as replication actually takes place at HDFS level. So, if you have just 1 node all your Hbase data will go there and if that server is down you are in the middle of nowhere. There are several advantages of having multiple DNs though, like lesser and balanced load on the machines vs all the load on a single machine, higher parallelism, high availability etc etc.